# Making Rows of Boxes Clickable with Links

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to make these boxes clickable with links for a while now, but haven't been able to figure it out. I'd like each box to have its own link. Can anyone help me refine my code?

https://jsfiddle.net/Anonymous32794/07suq4pg/8/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
    <img src="image" alt="">
  <div class="text">
    <b>Stuff</b>
    <button>Button</button>
    <p>Stuff</p></div> 
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Downloads</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box">Chapter 1</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 2</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 3</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 4</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 5</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 6</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 7</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 8</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 9</div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't the box just be an anchor element (`<a>`) with an `href`?

Comment: Do you mind explaining? Making it clickable isn't hard, but it seems to lose its formatting when I wrap the box with a link.

Comment: I was suggesting you could just replace `<div class="box">` with `<a class="box" href="...">`, there may be very minor style changes (e.g. text underline) but those can be removed with CSS if desired.

Comment: That certainly works, and you can even link just the text within the box, but that also removes the box itself, right?

Comment: It shouldn't do, you are still applying the `.box` class styling, give it a try and see.

Comment: I figured it out.
<div class="box-container">
      <a class="box" href="google.com">
        <span>Chapter</span>
        <span>1</span>
       </a>

Comment: @DBS Thanks for the help. It works perfectly...can't believe I didn't figure that out sooner. Let's say I want 10 boxes per row. How would I do that? And is there a way to shrink the text down depending on the size of the page? So that it would hide "Chapter" and only show the number.

Comment: I would recommend looking into "CSS Grid" for a layout like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you get all elements with class box. then you bind every element with a click Event Listener. Then you can handle the click event. In this case i print the innerHTML out.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert('will redirect to:' + e.target.getAttribute('data-href'));
    window.location = e.target.getAttribute('data-href');
  });  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center; 
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
.footer {
    
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
}

.aside-2 {
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
    top: 8px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.box {
    border: .1rem solid #cccccc;
    background: #5cc80f;
    color: white;
    width: 25%;
}
.box-container {
      align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-weight: 600;
    justify-content: left;
    min-width: 0;
}
.box::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
    
img {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 171px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 0 0; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
    <img src="image" alt="">
  <div class="text">
    <b>Stuff</b>
    <button>Button</button>
    <p>Stuff</p></div> 
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-2">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Downloads</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box" data-href="http://www.google.de">Chapter 1</div>
        <div class="box" data-href="http://www.bing.de">Chapter 2</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 3</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 4</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 5</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 6</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 7</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 8</div>
        <div class="box">Chapter 9</div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. My apologies. What I want to do is link each box to a separate page. So if you click on Chapter 1, it sends you to the Chapter 1 page.

Comment: @Anonymous23794 you can redirect with `window.location = "http://your-domain.com/chapter-1"` Replace this line with the alert and it will works!

Comment: Could this be used to automatically find the links to each chapter?
I discovered another way as well.
`<a class="box" href="google.com">
        <span>Chapter</span>
        <span>1</span>
      </a>`

Comment: @Anonymous23794 Yes you can do that with `window.location = e.target.getAttribute('href');`

Comment: Great. I guess I'll play around with it. Not very familiar with JS.